# Is oracle xmltable expression with multinode xpath preserve physical order of node?

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, oracle12c, xmltable

When having relational view on XML type. Could I guarantee that the order of elements are preserving the physical order you could find in XML document?

Example:

```
select *
from xmltable('root/level1' passing xmltype ('<root><level1><a>first</a></level1><level1><a>second</a></level1></root>')
columns col varchar2(2000) path '/a'
);
```

Could I quarantee that it is always

1. first
2. second

Background info: There is "client defined" ordering we have to keep. But in the XML document we do not have any attribute about this order. We must rely on the physical order provided in the xml document.

If order would reflect physical order then I could use rownum for ordering.

In my local tests order is preserved but I did not find any documentation about the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be rewritten to FLWR Expressions.

```
select *
from xmltable('for $i in ./root/level1 return $i ' passing xmltype ('<root><level1><a>first</a></level1><level1><a>second</a></level1></root>')
columns col varchar2(2000) path '/a'
);
```

Now you can check w3c specification for FLWR.[FLWR Expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-xquery-20010215/#section-FLWR-Expressions)

> ...and the order of the results is preserved in the output document....

And Oracle said  [xml db](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_xquery.htm#CBADAAIG)

> Oracle XML DB supports the latest version of the XQuery language specification, W3C XQuery 1.0 Recommendation. This section presents a brief overview of the language. For more information, consult a recent book on the language or refer to the standards documents that define it, which are available at http://www.w3c.org.

Comment: The full sentence is "_If an ordering exists among these tuples_, the RETURN-clause is executed on each tuple, in order, and the order of the results is preserved in  the output documend". Does it mean that the xpath matching is always happening in order?

Comment: Most probably yes. I have found the following (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model): "There is an ordering, document order, defined on all the nodes in the document corresponding to the order in which the first character of the XML representation of each node occurs in the XML representation of the document after expansion of general entities"

Comment: Moreover xpath allows to retrieve element by position . `element/element[1]`

Comment: Do you have experience with the `FOR ORDINALITY` column type in this case. E.g.: `select *
from xmltable('root/level1' passing xmltype ('<root><level1><a>first</a></level1><level1><a>second</a></level1></root>')
columns 
ord FOR ORDINALITY,
col varchar2(2000) path '/a'
) ;`